# JS error "Cannot read property 'timestamp'" at checkout after upgrade from 2.3.3 to 2.4.2-p1

Tags: checkout, javascript, error, magento2.4.2

I upgraded Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.2-p1 and at the checkout it presents this error and just keeps loading the checkout.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined
    at UiClass.checkCustomerData (defaultCaptcha.js:60)
    at UiClass.<anonymous> (defaultCaptcha.js:43)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:382)
    at UiClass.initialize (defaultCaptcha.js:38)
    at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
    at UiClass._super (wrapper.js:106)
    at UiClass.initialize (loginCaptcha.js:21)
    at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
    at new UiClass (class.js:49)
    at Object.initComponent (layout.js:137)
```

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed by removing all cookies for the site. Of course this can be difficult for customers to figure out so another solution would be preferable.

Comment: Right, after removing all cookies, it's working fine.